# How to set up many (five or six) organizations in a network, what are possible ways?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Looking at documentation in `Developing Applications` chapter under `The scenario` section there are introduced six organizations in a network - but just in theory - because in following sections of the same chapter, tutorial covers only two organizations.

Than in `Building your first network` tutorial once again we have only two organizations.
Moreover in `Adding an Org to a channel` tutorial we can see statement like this about adding third organization to a network of two organizations: 
`it’s one of the most complex channel configuration updates you can attempt.`

My question is how to set up network for 5 or 6 organizations in an easiest way without spending hours on configuration?

Or even to be more precise to begin with: Is there a way to have more than three organizations in a network `out of the box` to just focus on developing smart contracts? Because this statement from `Adding an Org to a channel` tutorial is confusing.

Why there is not a script for starting a network with more than two organizations in a `fabric-samples`?

Answer (score 2):

You can have the organizations you want. Instead of creating a 2-organization network and adding 4 organizations, create a 6-organization network from scratch. You normally create the network for all the expected organizations, and when later a new organization joins a consortium, then is when `configtxlator` plays its role.

Create the cryptographic material for the 6 organizations, include them in the `configtx.yaml`, create the genesis block and channel and anchor transactions with `configtxgen`, configure your peers and launch them.

You have "built your first network". OK, then may be time to build your second network and learn about all you (and the scripts) are doing. Don't expect to be creating your first network always.

Comment: yeah i know what you mean, i try to understand all those scripts, but without previous even minor 'administrator experience' it is quite challenging, could you specify which files i need to update except `configtx.yaml` and which commands i need to use to achieve my goal, or which chapter from tutorial is describing it? Also so far I've found some `hurley` npm package which generates a network easily, but i do not know if this will be fully functional later, do you know something about it?

Comment: `configtx.yaml`, `crypto-config.yaml` (for development) and every `docker-compose.yaml`, basically. In production use Fabric-CA instead of `crypto-config`, which is a mess the first times. A colleague uses that npm package for his tests and I think it is pretty decent, but neither that tool nor Hyperledger Cello allows me the fine-grain I require at work (it is not real one only person deploying all organizations and having access to all organizations' private keys), so I deploy my nodes manually (I have my own guides, templates and coarse scripts). I know it is not easy. Nobody said it was.